# sorting element in an object to be displayed using a while loop

Tags: php, sql, sorting, mysqli

I am creating a simple drop-down menu displaying names:

```
    $sql = "SELECT id, 
                name
            FROM team 
            WHERE 1";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->execute();    
    $stmt->store_result();

    $stmt->bind_result($id, $name);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            echo '<option value=\"$id\">'.utf8_encode($name).'</option>';
    }       
} else {
    header('Location: ../../error.php?err=the database is corrupted');
}
```

I want to sort the option by alphabetic order. I am not sure which function should I use to sort the object before the loop.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT id, 
                name
            FROM team 
            WHERE 1 ORDER BY name ASC";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `name` FROM team 
WHERE 1 ORDER BY name";
```

Default order of Database is `ASC`, so it works even if you do not write `ASC`.

Answer (score 1):

Do sorting in sql:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, 
                name
            FROM team 
            WHERE 1 order by name"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ORDER BY` in your query to get names sorted in alphabetical order.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name
        FROM team 
        WHERE 1
        ORDER BY name ASC";
```